# How to use Public Shared Sub to call functionality found in a Protected Sub goToRequestedPage() in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Here is my issue:

I have used the Javascript #Next 'on click' function to call the `Public Shared Sub NextPage()` method and also render my bookviewer in the "If-else" statement.

However, I now need the `Public Shared Sub NextPage()` method to call `Protected Sub goToRequestedPage()`. I know that I have to call another `Public Shared Sub` so I need to do something here to retrieve from the `goToRequestedPage()` method. Below is the `goToRequestedPage()` method I would like the 'Public Shared Sub' to call (or at least perform the statements within it).

`AutoSaveCheckBox`, `Label1`, and `Response`, all state the following error:"Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class."

As you can see, I would like a message box to pop up, asking the user to save, on top of allowing the user to go to the next page. The user is able to go to the next page, but how can I implement the `goToRequestPage()` method, or at least get my `msgbox` process to compile?

```
//Here is the Javascript 'on click' function for my next button:

$("#Next").click(function () {
                //PageMethods.NextPage(gbpageno)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebForm1.aspx/NextPage",
                    async: true,
                    data: "{'page':'" + gbPageNo + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () { },
                    error: function () { }
                });

                if (splitType == "v") {
                    RenderBR('#CenterLeft', gbPageNo + 1);
                }
                else {
                    RenderBR('#CenterTop', gbPageNo + 1);
                }
            });

//Here is the Public Shared Sub NextPage() method:

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> Public Shared Sub NextPage(ByVal page As Integer, ByVal textboxData As String)
        goToRequestedPage()
End Sub
```

//Here is the goToRequestedPage() method I would like to call from Public Shared Sub       //NextPage(), or at least retrieve all functionality within it (Originally, this was //Protected Sub goToRequestedPage()):

```
Public Shared Sub goToRequestedPage()
        ' Declare Variables:
        ' Declare TransTableAdapter
        Dim TransAdapter As New EOL_DataSetTableAdapters.TransTableAdapter
        ' Declare previous page save confirmation
        Dim previousPageSaveConfirmation As MsgBoxResult
        ' Declare next page save confirmation
        Dim nextPageSaveConfirmation As MsgBoxResult
        ' Declare autosave checkbox status as Boolean value
        Dim autoSaveCheckBoxStatus As Boolean
        ' Declare page link as String 
        Dim pgLink As String

        ' If autosave checkbox is CHECKED...
        If AutoSaveCheckBox.Checked = True Then
            ' Save (Either Insert or Update) Transcription and go to next page
            TransAdapter.Insert(DataID:="NOT ASSIGNED", ID:=1, Book:="Book1", Page:="Page1", User:="User1", urlPDF:="url1", Transcription:="Transcription1", Transcription_Text:=TranscriptionTextbox.Text, isMaster:=0, isLocked:=0, Timestamp:="2004-11-15 11:37:10", CreateDate:="2004-11-15 11:37:10")
            ' Add the incremented page link back to the String
            pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & gbCurrentPage & "/mode/1up"
            ' Declare Label 1 as The BookViewer on the Requested Page Number
            Label1.Text = "<object id=""BookViewer"" data=""" & pgLink & """ height=""500"" width=""1500""><embed src=""" & pgLink & """ width=""95%"" height=""100%""/>Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>"
            ' Redirect to the Global Current Page Number
            Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx?page=" & gbCurrentPage)

            ' If the autosave checkbox is UNCHECKED....
        Else
            If AutoSaveCheckBox.Checked = False Then
                'Display Yes/No Save Confirmation
                MsgBox("Would you like to save before continuing to the next page?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")

                ' For Previous Case:
                If previousPageSaveConfirmation = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    ' Decrement Global Current Page Number by one page if greater than page 1:
                    'If gbCurrentPage > 1 Then gbCurrentPage -= 1
                    ' Save (Either Insert or Update) Transcription
                    TransAdapter.Insert(DataID:="NOT ASSIGNED", ID:=1, Book:="Book1", Page:="Page1", User:="User1", urlPDF:="url1", Transcription:="Transcription1", Transcription_Text:=TranscriptionTextbox.Text, isMaster:=0, isLocked:=0, Timestamp:="2004-11-15 11:37:10", CreateDate:="2004-11-15 11:37:10")
                    ' Add the decremented page link back to the String
                    pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & gbCurrentPage & "/mode/1up"
                    ' Declare Label 1
                    Label1.Text = "<object id=""BookViewer"" data=""" & pgLink & """ height=""500"" width=""1500""><embed src=""" & pgLink & """ width=""95%"" height=""100%""/>Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>"
                    ' Redirect to the Global Current Page Number
                    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx?page=" & gbCurrentPage)
                ElseIf previousPageSaveConfirmation = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                    ' Decrement Global Current Page Number by one page if greater than page 1:
                    'If gbCurrentPage > 1 Then gbCurrentPage -= 1
                    ' Go to Previous Page:
                    ' Add the decremented page link back to the String
                    pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & gbCurrentPage & "/mode/1up"
                    ' Add the incremented page link back to the String
                    pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & gbCurrentPage & "/mode/1up"
                    ' Declare Label 1
                    Label1.Text = "<object id=""BookViewer"" data=""" & pgLink & """ height=""500"" width=""1500""><embed src=""" & pgLink & """ width=""95%"" height=""100%""/>Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>"
                    ' Redirect to the Global Current Page Number
                    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx?page=" & gbCurrentPage)
                End If

                ' For Next Case:
                If nextPageSaveConfirmation = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    ' Increment global current page number by one page
                    'gbCurrentPage += 1
                    ' Save (Either Insert or Update) Transcription and go to next page
                    TransAdapter.Insert(DataID:="NOT ASSIGNED", ID:=1, Book:="Book1", Page:="Page1", User:="User1", urlPDF:="url1", Transcription:="Transcription1", Transcription_Text:=TranscriptionTextbox.Text, isMaster:=0, isLocked:=0, Timestamp:="2004-11-15 11:37:10", CreateDate:="2004-11-15 11:37:10")
                    ' Add the incremented page link back to the String
                    pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & gbCurrentPage & "/mode/1up"
                    ' Declare Label 1
                    Label1.Text = "<object id=""BookViewer"" data=""" & pgLink & """ height=""500"" width=""1500""><embed src=""" & pgLink & """ width=""95%"" height=""100%""/>Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>"
                    ' Redirect to the Global Current Page Number
                    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx?page=" & gbCurrentPage)
                ElseIf nextPageSaveConfirmation = MsgBoxResult.No Then
                    ' Increment global current page number by one page
                    'gbCurrentPage += 1
                    ' Go to next page:
                    ' Add the incremented page link back to the String
                    pgLink = "http://br.mdsa.net/BookReader/index.html?id=ce425&item=1&format=Bitonal#page/" & gbCurrentPage & "/mode/1up"
                    ' Declare Label 1
                    Label1.Text = "<object id=""BookViewer"" data=""" & pgLink & """ height=""500"" width=""1500""><embed src=""" & pgLink & """ width=""95%"" height=""100%""/>Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.</object>"
                    ' Redirect to the Global Current Page Number
                    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx?page=" & gbCurrentPage)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: So why can't you just leave it as `Shared`?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says you cannot call an instanced - not shared member from the shared method. So for example consider this setup:

```
Public Class Testing

  Public Shared Function Test1() As String
      Dim value = Test2()
      return value
  End Function

  Public Function Test2() As String
      return "Some text..."
  End Function

End Class
```

This will not work since you are trying to invoke a non shared method Test2 from within a shared method Test1. The reason why it will not work is because method Test2 requires an instance of Testing class in order to be invoke - it can only be invoked via that instance. To fix this issue you have 2 options:

1. Make method Test 2 be shared too.
2. Fix the code in the following manner:

   ```
   Public Class Testing

     Public Shared Function Test1() As String
       Dim instance = New Testing()
       Dim value = instance.Test2()
       return value
     End Function

     Public Function Test2() As String
       return "Some text..."
     End Function

   End Class
   ```